# How do I verify noise coming into my home from the outside?

Tags: noise

I'm fairly certain I've located the source of noise I've been hearing coming into my home; about 98.999% certain; however I need verification from an outside source like a sound engineer, etc.

Does anyone know how I would go about proving the source of the noise?

Sounds easy to just hire a sound engineer, but what are the costs involved and how many are willing to step up to help a residential issue? Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the noise, why you need to locate it, and where you think it is coming from?

Comment: get a highly direction mic, like a shotgun and wave it around until the sound is loudest; it will then point to the source. you can make a lo-fi version by putting a cheap mic at the end of a paper towel roll, full is better, and stuffing cloth in the mic end to hold in place.

Comment: If we don't understand the noise or how this pertains to a home there is no way to answer it.   If this is about a neighbor yelling at his wife, this isn't the site.   If the noise is a street light doing some serious humming we may be able to help.

Comment: If you step outside and cannot hear it I can't see how it's the source of your noise.

Comment: Quite possible it is a bad bearing on an airconditioner. I wish you well contacting the owners.